# How to get the content of google doc in google apps?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am having a problem in to fetch the content of the document. I am able to fetch the document id but couldn't get the document's text.
I am using the following code for this:

```
function getDocuments(user){
  var scope = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
  //oAuth
  user="email-id"
  var fetchArgs = googleOAuth_('docs', scope);
  var url = scope + user+'/private/full?v=3&alt=json';
  var urlFetch = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchArgs);
  var json=Utilities.jsonParse(urlFetch.getContentText())
  var entry = json.feed.entry;
  var docs = [];
  for(var i in entry){
    var tempDoc = {};
    for(var j in entry[i]){

      tempDoc.id = entry[i].id.$t.split('%3A')[1];
    }
    docs.push(tempDoc);
    //Logger.log(docs[i])
  }


  var url='https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/Export?docID=?'

  var data=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,fetchArgs).getAs('text/html').getDataAsString()
  MailApp.sendEmail("email","","",{htmlBody:data})
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Google oAuth
//Used by getDocuments(user)
function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey("consumerkey");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret(consumersecret);
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always",method:"GET"};
}
```

It returns html format of document but, couldn't return the content of document.
Please share me any suggestion asap..

Comment: What do you want to do with the document content ? display it in an UI ? send it as mail ? And also : do you want the full format or only text ?

Comment: I want to store it on google cloud storage. and want full format of the document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want the doc to be the html body of a mail you can use this code :

```
    var id = 'the ID of your document'
    var bodytext = DocumentApp.openById(id).getText();//the text content of your doc (optional)
    var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
    var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+'download/documents/Export?exportFormat=html&format=html&id='+id,
    googleOAuth_('docs',url)).getContentText(); 


    MailApp.sendEmail(destination email, subject, bodytext, {htmlBody:doc});
```

and the OAuth function :

```
function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so far I do not know any function that can get the contents of the file, you can refer to the document with the file sharing link.

i hope help you!